# Xgboost Underfitting

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

i trained the following Xgboost classifier :

```
xgb.XGBClassifier(tree_method='hist', grow_policy='lossguide',gamma=1.0, max_depth=0, max_leaves=255,  min_child_weight=100,n_estimators=500,
                    n_jobs=-1,
                    learning_rate=0.1,
                    subsample=0.7,
                    colsample_bytree=0.7,
                   )
```

I ploted the learning curves (log loss vs epoch) for the training set and the validation set.

[The learning curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1S9o.png) that i got are **exactly the same for the training and the validation set**: log loss decreases at the beginning from 0.6 to 0.3 and then plateau after 100 epochs

I believe that this is a case of **underfitting** ? giving that i have a high bias.

How can i complexify the model in this case?

Any help is very much appreciated

Thank you

Comment: you have `max_depth` set to `0`

Comment: In the doc they say the following : max_depth: maximum depth. Behaves as usual when grow_policy is set to depthwise. If grow_policy is lossguide, max_depth can be set to zero, indicating the lack of limit on depth, so technically that is not a problem

Comment: Happening with me too. Did you get any solution for this?